# Merging entries of 2 String lists in Java 8

Tags: string, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 input lists, list1 = ["a","b","c"] and list2 = ["1","2","3"]. Given that the size of both lists is always bound to be the same, i need a resultant list that reads ["a1","a2","a3"].

While this can be done easily in earlier Java versions, I am interested to know how this can be achieved using Streams in Java 8.

Comment: You're looking for the `zip` operation that, unfortunately, doesn't directly exist in Java 8. See the linked question.

Comment: Thanks... The attached link helped...

Comment: Actually here, since you have lists of equals lengths you could use an `IntStream`: `List<String> res = IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).mapToObj(i -> list1.get(i)+list2.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Thanks Alexis. The solution worked like a theorem...